# Minecraft JAVA server plugins not loading with no errors in the logs / Minecraft JAVA server DEBUG log mode

Tags: minecraft

Helping my son to roll out a Minecraft JAVA Linux server.
Adding new plugins however nothing is loaded without any error.
Played with plugins folder and plugin files permissions - made them chmod 777, still no success.
Didn't find even any info on how to switch on the DEBUG log level
Would really appreciate on any help

Comment: Hi, this site is for programming questions. As per this [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354760/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-modding-minecraft) it would be better to ask on [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty clear and from the RTFM section.
Vanilla Minecraft server doesn't allow to use plugins. You should use Bukkit, Spigot and other modifications if you want to add plugins to your server.